# How to draw a large wordnet/mindmap in Tikz with as little manual specification as possible

Tags: tikz-pgf, bibtex

In order to organize the extensive literature for my research, I had the idea to create a large graphical network of papers so that I can show visually how they are linked to each other. I would like to do this in Tikz, ideally in such a way that I can enter only the node labels and which other nodes they are connected to and Tikz would generate their positions and connecting lines automatically upon compilation (according to some criterion of optimality). The reason for this approach is that I have a rather large number of nodes, many of which are connected to many others, so that I cannot specify each connecting line individually.

In an ideal world, I would find a solution which allows me to access my BibTeX database and use the BibTeX keys to indicate which nodes are connected to which others. Also, it would be nice to be able to distinguish between strands of literature (e.g. empirical, theoretical, legal, etc.) perhaps using colors and/or grouping of nodes. Unfortunately this is well beyond the scope of my competencies in Tikz, so I am hoping someone will like the idea and have some suggestions.

In terms of the final output, I am aiming for something rather organic and non-hierarchical (see below; I am not too fond of the look of this particular graph, but the structure is much more important.).

[image: Stolen from texample.net]

Comment: An example would help, even if it's initially full of manual adjustments. This allows other people to have a feeling of what output you have in mind. Then they could improve your code or suggest alternative methods that make the process more efficient.